# how to get a existent aws lambda source code using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have several aws lambda functions and I want to download all the source code, in separated zip files(preferably, this is the way I uploaded them).

I was able to list the functions and configurations but not to get the source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this via `get-function`:

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name foo --query 'Code.Location'
```

This returns a pre-signed URL you can use to download the function's .zip file that you previously uploaded. The URL is valid for up to 10 minutes.

See: [`get-function` — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the AWS web console.
Select your lambda and under the actions, you can see 'export function' option.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward command line way with `wget` and `jq` installed:

```
wget $(aws lambda get-function --function-name my-function --query 'Code.Location' --region eu-central-1 | jq '.' -r | tr -d '\n')
```